# Replacing values for dichotomous variable based on matching ID in R

Tags: r

```
test <- data.frame('id'= rep(1:3,3), 'Dich'= c(NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 1, 1, NA))
test
  id Dich
1  1   NA
2  2   NA
3  3   NA
4  1    1
5  2   NA
6  3   NA
7  1    1
8  2    1
9  3   NA
```

I want to replace missing values with 1 if the matching ID has the value of 1 in any other row.

Ideal outcome:

```
     id Dich
1  1    1
2  2    1
3  3   NA
4  1    1
5  2    1
6  3   NA
7  1    1
8  2    1
9  3   NA
```

Thanks!

Comment: row 6, ID=3 has value 1 why is it not 1 in the desired outcome?

Comment: Oops! I thought I had changed that. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `any`

```
transform(test, Dich2 = ave(x = Dich, id, FUN = any))
#  id Dich Dich2
#1  1   NA     1
#2  2   NA     1
#3  3   NA    NA
#4  1    1     1
#5  2   NA     1
#6  3   NA    NA
#7  1    1     1
#8  2    1     1
#9  3   NA    NA
```

This works because `any(c(1, NA))` returns `TRUE` (and a warning) and `ave` returns a numeric vector.

Comment: Wonderful! Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

data.table solution:

```
data.table::setDT(test)[,Dich:=ifelse(is.na(Dich)&any(Dich%in%1),1,Dich),by="id"]

#   id Dich
#1:  1    1
#2:  2    1
#3:  3   NA
#4:  1    1
#5:  2    1
#6:  3   NA
#7:  1    1
#8:  2    1
#9:  3   NA
```